# Mismatch Error in Microsoft Access Database login form

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I get a run time 13 error = "mismatch error" in my login form in the Access Database.
Currently the form works for members and successfully logs them in however when I try to enter correct login details from the trainer table I get the run time error.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    If IsNull(Me.txtEmail) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Email Address", vbInformation, "Email Requeired"
        Me.txtEmail.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Email Address", vbInformation, "Email Requeired"
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Else
       'process the job'
        If (IsNull(DLookup("MemberEmail", "TBL_Members", "MemberEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And MemberPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")) Or (DLookup("TrainerEmail", "TBL_Trainers", "TrainerEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And TrainerPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!"
        Else
            MemberEmail = DLookup("[MemberEmail]", "TBL_Members", "[MemberEmail] = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "'")
            TrainerEmail = DLookup("[TrainerEmail]", "TBL_Trainers", "[TrainerEmail] = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "'")
            SecurityLevel = DLookup("[SecurityLevel]", "TBL_Members", "[MemberEmail] = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "'")
            DoCmd.Close
            If (TempPass = "password") Then
                MsgBox "Please change Password", vbInformation, "New password required"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserinfo", , , "[UserLogin] = " & UserLogin
            Else
                'open different form according to user level
                If SecurityLevel = 1 Then ' for Members
                    DoCmd.OpenForm "Admin"
                Else
                    DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
                End If

            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.txtEmail.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line of code is the error occurring?

Comment: If (IsNull(DLookup("MemberEmail", "TBL_Members", "MemberEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And MemberPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")) Or (DLookup("TrainerEmail", "TBL_Trainers", "TrainerEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And TrainerPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
 seems to be the OR statment

Comment: Does your password verification differentiate between upper-case and lower-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this expression:

```
If (IsNull(DLookup("MemberEmail", "TBL_Members", "MemberEmail = '" & _
    Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And MemberPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")) _
    Or (DLookup("TrainerEmail", "TBL_Trainers", "TrainerEmail = '" & _
    Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And TrainerPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) _
Then
```

Let's add some variables to make it easier to read:

```
Dim varM As Variant
Dim varT As Variant

varM = DLookup("MemberEmail", "TBL_Members", "MemberEmail = '" & _
    Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And MemberPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))
varT = DLookup("TrainerEmail", "TBL_Trainers", "TrainerEmail = '" & _
    Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And TrainerPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))

If (IsNull(varM Or varT)) Then
```

The problem is that `Or` requires Boolean or numeric operands, but you're applying it to e-mail addresses and then checking whether the result is null.  What you really want to do is check whether each is null and then use the results of those expressions as the operands for `Or`:

```
If (IsNull(varM) Or IsNull(varT)) Then
```

Furthermore, as pointed out in a comment, the operator should be `And`, not `Or`, since you would never expect both of the values to be non-null:

```
If (IsNull(varM) And IsNull(varT)) Then
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to fix that in the original expression without the variables.

Comment: When trying to attempt things using your sollution i found out that the program would not allow members from any of the tables to log in. However I split up the registration proccess to 2 if statments and it now works as intented but I just get a invalid username or password text box apprering when ever correct username has been entered. Any way to close the form before the next if statment. I tried Me.close() but that does not work.

Comment: If (IsNull(DLookup("MemberEmail", "TBL_Members", "MemberEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And MemberPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
    Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Admin"
    If (IsNull(DLookup("TrainerEmail", "TBL_Trainers", "TrainerEmail = '" & Me.txtEmail.Value & "' And TrainerPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!"

Comment: The two `IsNull` checks should be connected via `And`.

Comment: @WolfgangKais that does indeed seem to make more sense.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you very much  I tried and yesterday but i must have messed up  somewhere. I updated the code with the AND statement today and it works perfectly thank you very much for this help